# What's a pre-multiplied 4x4 matrix?

Tags: 3d, mathematics, camera, matrix, projection

I'm using a 3d game engine, that uses a 4x4 matrix to modify the camera projection.

The matrix is in the regular 4x4 format:

```
 r r r  x
 r r r  y
 r r r  z
 - - -  zoom
```

The description for the matrix class says:

> A transformation matrix. Matrices are pre-multiplication, as in: x' =
>   M*x.

What does this mean?

Comment: There is no _regular_ 4x4 matrix format, only row- and column-major form. Your example is in column-major form, as used for instance in OpenGL.

Comment: Check this link. It's explained in detail: http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-4-geometry/conventions-again-row-major-vs-column-major-vector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not saying the matrices are *pre-multiplied* but rather that they are (read use) *pre-multiplication*.

This basically specifies the correct order of multiplication when using them, such that when multiplying a matrix by a vector, the matrix needs comes first.

In other words, this:

```
result = matrix * vector
```

Instead of:

```
result = vector * matrix
```

Answer (score 6):

Pre- or post-multiplication just defines the order of operations how the member of that matrix and vector are multiplied, its purely a notational convention.

The common operations in 3D graphics are post-multiplying a row-vector with column-major matrices (OpenGL) and pre-multiplying a column-vector with row-major matrices (DirectX).

Both are basically the same operations with the same results, just the notational convention is different.